# background only at login with ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, nvidia

I'm am currently having an issue with my GUI. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and when I log in all I see is the mouse pointer and my background image.

The output of my .xsessions-errors file is:

```
Libgl error: failed to load driver: swrast
Script for ibus started at run_im
Script for auto started at run_im
Script for default started at run_im
```

Any ideas?

I have tried a package search for swrast(nothing) and I have done some googling and there seems to be this issue with swrast with games in linux and did not help.

I am have an nvidia graphics card, 650m and using nvidia drivers. I believe there is probably an issue there. If more output is needed let me know what commands to run and I will update this question. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you right-click on the desktop?

Comment: I actually just fixed i by installing gdm instead of lightdm. Then I reinstalled nvidia drivers. Generated new xorg configuration file and then I was allowed by the nvidia gods to use my damn computer. How generous of them.

Comment: Okay. Reason I asked was I'd experienced a superficially similar issue with the compiz unity plugin being disabled on login, and had to add a new folder to the desktop, use said folder as a means of accessing the filesystem, and manually run ccsm to re-enable the plugin.

Comment: I actually wish I could go back and see if that was possible. The things we endure for open source. Would